# Error installing mariadb-server mariadb-client on Chromebook

Tags: linux, wordpress, mariadb, chromebook

I'm trying install wordpress locally on my chromebook following [these instructions](https://chromeready.com/4464/install-wordpress-chromebook/).

I successfully ran:
`

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install nano
```

`

But then get an error when I try to run
`

```
sudo apt install mariadb-server mariadb-client -y
```

`

Here's the error from my terminal:
`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libdbi-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.32.0
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

`

I'm a complete newb at Linux and spend hours googling / trying solutions to no avail. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't reproduce on my Chromebook. Please post the results of the commands below.
cat /etc/debian_version, cat /proe/version

Comment: `cat /etc/debian version:  11.6 `  
`cat /proe/version: No such file or directory`

Comment: The youtube link was super helpful, but the link for the bitnami wordpress linux installer no longer works: https://www.apachefriends.org/bitnami_for_xampp.html. Is there a new location?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong. It should be "cat /proc/version".

Comment: `cat /proc/version
Linux version 5.10.147-20158-g0a75306e5639 (chrome-bot@chromeos-release-builder-us-central1-a-x32-3-jscm) (Chromium OS 15.0_pre465103_p20220825-r3 clang version 15.0.0 (/var/tmp/portage/sys-devel/llvm-15.0_pre465103_p20220825-r3/work/llvm-15.0_pre465103_p20220825/clang db1978b67431ca3462ad8935bf662c15750b8252), LLD 15.0.0) #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Nov 27 20:52:05 PST 2022`

Comment: Why did you hide the bitnami wordpress linux installer video?  That was super helpful.

Comment: I tried the 2nd Video and received the error:
`~/my_wordpress$ sudo -g docker docker compose up -d
sudo: unknown group: docker
sudo: error initializing audit plugin sudoers_audit`

Comment: The Debian and Linux versions are the same as mine. Reinstalling Linux may fix the problem.